# Adding final children "automatically" within object

Tags: java, field, children

I want to build a java data structure with an universal Obj class with inner Obj objects. Here is an example:

```
public final Obj x = new Obj() {
  public final Obj y = new Obj(3);
  public final Obj z = new Obj() {
    public final Obj a = new Obj(3);
    public final Obj b = new Obj(4);
  }
};
```

Of course, that runs: I can use variables x or x.y or x.z.a and so on.

My problem is: Every leaf object has a fix size (here given to the constructor as an int value) and an index within the upper object. The parent objects have size of sum of the children:

```
a and y has size 3
b has size 4
--> z has size 7
... --> x has size 10

y and a have index 0
z and b have index 1
```

Of course I could realize it by giving the parent as part of the constructor:

```
public final Obj x = new Obj() {
  public final Obj y = new Obj(x, 3);
  public final Obj z = new Obj(x) {
    public final Obj a = new Obj(z, 3);
    public final Obj b = new Obj(z, 4);
  }
};
```

But I want to do this "magic" - is there a way to do it?

I need one of two things:

1) A method that runs after all inner fields have been added (so I can get all inner objects by reflection).

2) Or a technic to tell something to the upper object (so object in y tells object in x "Hey, I'm your son!").

I tried to use object initializing blocks, but all of them are running pairwise with the constructor: Initializing blocks of x, then constructor of x, then initializing blocks of y, ...

Hope, my problem is described clearly.

Thanks a lot for every help!

Comment: This is rather unclear and looks very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Please describe the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve instead.

Comment: Well, my problem is how I told. I don't know how to explain better. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Okay, I will try it better: Is there an ("automatic") way that object in x tells object in y that it is a child of it?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to model, not how you think the model should look.

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to. It's a question of "art", not of modelling. I know how to Code and how to model. The upper code will be generated by a tool and shall be expandable by programmer. So it shall be easy.